# Not understanding factory functions properly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the differences of inheritence in JavaScript.

Now I am trying to change the **first** code into a factory function (**second** code). But how can I use the methods of the EventEmitter inside it?

I've been wrestling with this code for about 5 hours, and I've read all the blogs I could find on this topic. Therefore some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Prototypal delegation way**

```
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

module.exports = Clock;

function Clock() {

  if ( ! (this instanceof Clock)) return new Clock();
  this._started = false;

  EventEmitter.call(this);

}

inherits(Clock, EventEmitter);

Clock.prototype.start = function start() {

  var self = this;

  if (self._started) return;

  var tic = true;

  this._started = Date.now();

  self._interval = setInterval(function() {
    var event = tic ? 'tic' : 'toc';
    self.emit(event, self.time());
    tic = ! tic;
  }, 1000);
};

Clock.prototype.stop = function stop() {
  clearInterval(this._interval);
  this._started = false;
};

Clock.prototype.time = function() {
  return this._started && Date.now() - this._started;
};
```

**Concatenative inheritence way - Factory function**

```
var eventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

const clock = () => {

  let started = false;

  let interval;

  //eventEmitter.call(this);

  self = {

    isStarted: function() {
      return started;
    },

    start: function() {
      let tic = true;

      if (started) return;
      started = Date.now();

      interval = setInterval(function() {
        let event = tic ? 'tic' : 'toc';
        this.emit(event);
      })

    },

  }

  return Object.assign({}, self, eventEmitter);
};


var clock1 = clock()
```

Comment: First, `self` doesn't have a proper declaration. Make sure you scope it to the function. In the return value, I think you wanted `return Object.assign({}, self, eventEmitter.prototype)` so that you get the inherited methods. However I don't know if that actually gives you everything you need since there could be levels of inheritance above that, in which case inheritance would probably just be simpler, though you can do it with `let self = Object.create(eventEmitter.prototype)`.

Comment: ...and then you'll still need `eventEmitter.call(self);` either way I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function clock() {
  let started = false;
  let interval;

  return Object.assign(new EventEmitter(), {
    isStarted() {
      return started;
    },
    start() {
      …
    }
  });
}

var clock1 = clock();
```

Comment: This seems like a very clean solution, however I'm not sure how to use the EventEmitter's methods in the new object though. In the start() method, how can I use the emit() function?

Comment: Just `this.emit(…)`, as you'd do with every other method.

Comment: TypeError: this.emit is not a function

Comment: How do you call `start`?

Comment: clock1.start();

Comment: Hm, that should work fine. What does `console.log(this, Object.keys(this), Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)));` log in `start`?

Comment: this logs: EventEmitter {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  isStarted: [Function: isStarted],
  start: [Function: start] }

Comment: Object.keys(this) logs: [ 'domain',
  '_events',
  '_eventsCount',
  '_maxListeners',
  'isStarted',
  'start' ]

Comment: Object.getPrototypeOf(this) logs: [ 'domain',
  '_events',
  '_maxListeners',
  'setMaxListeners',
  'getMaxListeners',
  'emit',
  'addListener',
  'on',
  'prependListener',
  'once',
  'prependOnceListener',
  'removeListener',
  'removeAllListeners',
  'listeners',
  'listenerCount',
  'eventNames' ]

Comment: Then `this.emit()` does work. Are you sure you're not calling `start` anywhere else, in a different way so that `this` is not defined?

Comment: I am really sure.

Comment: I fixed it. It is because I was calling it from a setInterval function. So I made a var self = this; and called it in there with self.emit()